# how do I reprint the loops output, outside the loops

Tags: java

**Problem:**
How do I reprint the for-loops output, outside the loop? Need help to figure it out. what seems to be the error?

**Research effort:**

```
  **import java.util.*;
public class Admin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        ArrayList <String> title = new ArrayList<>();

        String n = in.nextLine();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while(!n.equals(" ")){
              System.out.println("Enter a movie title");
            title.add(n);
            n = in.nextLine();
        }

        for(;i < title.size(); i++){

            System.out.println("[" + i +"]" +title.get(i));
        }
                int [] price = new int [title.size()];


        for(;j < price.length; j++ ){
            System.out.println("Enter price for");
            price[j] = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Price for ["+j+"] is "+ price[j]  );

        }
          //the problem
               System.out.println("["+ i+"]"+title.get(i)+" Price: "+price[j] );


        }
  }
```

every time I run it after the loops, error shows up 
Expected Result: is that it will print the "i" and "title[i]" together with the "j" and "price[j]" both outside it's loops

Comment: What do you mean by reprinting the output? You can store it in string array and print it later, if that is what you are asking. Please include current output and required output, and explain clearly what is required.

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve through your code.

Comment: Add expected result, please.

Comment: Hi, the last line that you can't print because you are not in a loop, then you should to do a loop again for print both `title and price` as you stored on arrays then you should iterate it on a for something like `for(; x<title.lenght; x++) { printLn(" " + x + title.get(x) + prove[x] )`

Comment: What's your expected result _exactly_? Let's say I entered three movie title and price. `Title1 Title2 Title3 100 200 300` What will the line outside the loop print?

Comment: like that one, but in the format like this
example:
[0]title0 Price: 100
[1]title1 Price: 200
[2]title2 Price: 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to see something like this:

```
[0]MovieTitle1 Price: MoviePrice1
[1]MovieTitle2 Price: MoviePrice2
```

There are some Problems: At first, you are going to get an IndexOutOfBoundsException,
because `i` and `j` have been increased to `title.size()`. This is because of the two for-Loops.

In my example this means that `i == 2` and `j == 2` are true after execution of both for-Loops has happened.

The `title` ArrayList and the `price` Array know the Entrys 0 and 1 (in my example) - you are trying to access Entry 2 which is out of bounds.

A possible solution would be to change this:

```
System.out.println("["+ i+"]"+title.get(i)+" Price: "+price[j] );
```

to something like this:

```
for(int n = 0; n < title.size(); n++) {
    System.out.println("[" + n + "]" + title.get(n) + " Price: " + price[n]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that really helps me a lot.. sorry for giving you guys a hardtime to understand, I'm not really good in english.. Thank you again

Comment: @MoisesMogol no problem. If your problem is solved, please click the "accep this answer" button next to my answer :)